# jQuery Validate plugin: at least 1 checkbox, multiple groups, using data-foo instead of class or id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Situation: multiple forms on page, multiple sets of checkboxes in each form.  Checkboxes look like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="$opt" name="$ID.$opt[]" value="$opt" >
```

I cant change or add to the class or id because of unrelated but interfering factors.  I found some other pieces to this puzzle, but wasnt sure how to use them, esp given that I want to validate multiple groups of checkboxes per form.

I tried this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validate-checkbox-oneormore', function (value) {
    return jQuery('.require-one:checked').size() != 0; }, 'need a value');
```

I put it under the actual plugin script, just after it in the file.  I'm going to use this functionality most of the time i am validating, so it might as well be part of the plugin.

How can I run this validation using data attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
return jQuery('[data-foo=bar]:checked').size() != 0;
```

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/CRVSx/1/)

UPDATE:

You also need a rule that says that the "checkone" method should be run on some form field:

```
$(function() {
    $("#form1").validate();
    $("#form1 input[data-foo=bar]").rules("add", {
        checkone: true
    });
});​
```

See my update of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ceUkK/8/)

Comment: I'm probly not doing it right.  I've got 

`<input type="checkbox" value="Lettuce" id="Lettuce" name="682-Vegetables[]" data-foo="bar">`

and 

`jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkone", function (value) {
        return jQuery('[data-foo="bar"]:checked').size() != 0;
  }
  , 'need a value');`
after the plugin script and a section of

`jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "",//This field is required. etc
});`

I tried with and without quotes on data-foo=bar.

Comment: Works for me, see the fiddle.

Comment: Oh, i see that it works, in that basic form.  But I would like to use it with the validator plugin, and have it be an extension of the plugin.  I am very unskilled in js syntax, functions, etc, I dont know how to implement this.  Also, I need to have multiple groups per form, so it would probly be like `<input data-rule="checkone" data-ruleGroup="veggies">` and then there would also be another group of checkboxes, eg `data-ruleGroup="condiments"`

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that shows what you're trying, I don't feel like trying to set all that up myself.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that works for the normal text box validation, but not the checkboxes http://jsfiddle.net/DougCassidy/ceUkK/7/

Comment: You don't have any rules saying that the "checkone" method should be run.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.  So, 2 things.  Is there a way to extend the plugin so that it always has the checkbox validation?  Is there a way to automagically group boxes?  Maybe have it key on data-rule='checkone' and then look at the name= to group them together?

Comment: Currently it's organized around validating fields, not the form as a whole -- you have to attach rules to fields by name or ID. But the code is available, so you can extend it as you like.